# How to set the size of a svgPath in JavaFx

Tags: java, svg, javafx

I have a ListView that contains ListCells, which contain an icon defined by a SvgPath.

```
private class CustomCell extends ListCell<String> {
    private SVGPath icon = new SVGPath();

    public CustomCell() {
        icon.setContent("...");
    }

    @Override
    public void updateItem(String value, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(value, empty);
        if(empty || value == null) {
            setGraphic(null);
            setText(null);
        } else {
            setGraphic(icon);
            setText(value);
        }
    }
}
```

I want the icon to fill the height of the list cell (which is about 30px). But it´s always shown extremely large, and the size of the cell is set to the height of the icon.

Even if I set the size of the list cell and the icon

```
public CustomCell()
{
    setPrefHeight(30);
    setMaxHeight(30);
    icon.setContent("...");
    icon.maxHeight(30);
    icon.prefHeight(30);
}
```

it doesn´t work. The height of the list cell is correct, but the icon still is shown too large.

Where am I wrong?

EDIT:
This is the path of my svg:

```
M 289.00,74.00 C 299.18,61.21 307.32,52.80 320.00,42.42 331.43,33.07 343.66,26.03 357.00,19.84 427.64,-12.98 509.92,2.91 564.42,58.28 583.93,78.10 595.94,99.15 605.58,125.00 607.76,130.86 611.37,144.75 612.54,151.00 613.15,154.23 613.28,160.06 615.58,162.44 617.49,164.42 624.11,165.84 627.00,166.86 634.80,169.62 639.97,172.04 647.00,176.42 673.69,193.07 692.76,221.39 695.83,253.00 700.60,302.03 676.64,345.41 630.00,364.00 621.17,367.52 608.48,370.99 599.00,371.00 599.00,371.00 106.00,371.00 106.00,371.00 96.50,370.99 87.00,368.97 78.00,366.00 36.29,352.22 6.21,312.25 6.00,268.00 5.77,219.90 34.76,179.34 81.00,165.02 96.78,160.14 107.02,161.00 123.00,161.00 124.59,150.68 130.49,137.79 136.05,129.00 150.70,105.88 173.22,88.99 200.00,82.65 213.13,79.55 219.79,79.85 233.00,80.00 247.37,80.17 264.61,85.94 277.00,93.00 279.11,86.37 284.67,79.45 289.00,74.00 Z
```

[image]

Its a cloud which I want to show in a specific size (e.g. 30, 30).
But I can´t find a way how to set a specific size.

Comment: [JavaFX - How to resize a SVG Path right in a TableView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38913567/javafx-how-to-resize-a-svg-path-right-in-a-tableview) shows how you can use a group to wrap SVGPath to decrease its size.

Comment: Thanks. But somehow it doesnt work for me. The icon is not visible.

Comment: May be if you can add a MCVE to your question to help you better.

Comment: What do you mean with MCVE?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

## Use a Region

After using SVGPath for sometime, I found its best to set it as a shape to a Region and define min/pref/max size on this region. This way their is no need to use the scaleX/Y factors, which leads to a difference in layout bounds and bounds in parent sizes.

To achieve this, we need to:

- Define a new Region and set the SVGPath as the shape.
- Define the min/pref/max size for this region.
- Set a background color for this region which gets set as the fill for the svg shape.

**MCVE**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.shape.SVGPath;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class SVGPathResize extends Application {

    private static final double REQUIRED_WIDTH = 50.0;
    private static final double REQUIRED_HEIGHT = 30.0;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        SVGPath svg = new SVGPath();
        svg.setContent("M 289.00,74.00 C 299.18,61.21 307.32,52.80 320.00,42.42 331.43,33.07 343.66,26.03 357.00,19.84 427.64,-12.98 509.92,2.91 564.42,58.28 583.93,78.10 595.94,99.15 605.58,125.00 607.76,130.86 611.37,144.75 612.54,151.00 613.15,154.23 613.28,160.06 615.58,162.44 617.49,164.42 624.11,165.84 627.00,166.86 634.80,169.62 639.97,172.04 647.00,176.42 673.69,193.07 692.76,221.39 695.83,253.00 700.60,302.03 676.64,345.41 630.00,364.00 621.17,367.52 608.48,370.99 599.00,371.00 599.00,371.00 106.00,371.00 106.00,371.00 96.50,370.99 87.00,368.97 78.00,366.00 36.29,352.22 6.21,312.25 6.00,268.00 5.77,219.90 34.76,179.34 81.00,165.02 96.78,160.14 107.02,161.00 123.00,161.00 124.59,150.68 130.49,137.79 136.05,129.00 150.70,105.88 173.22,88.99 200.00,82.65 213.13,79.55 219.79,79.85 233.00,80.00 247.37,80.17 264.61,85.94 277.00,93.00 279.11,86.37 284.67,79.45 289.00,74.00 Z");
        final Region svgShape = new Region();
        svgShape.setShape(svg);
        svgShape.setMinSize(REQUIRED_WIDTH, REQUIRED_HEIGHT);
        svgShape.setPrefSize(REQUIRED_WIDTH, REQUIRED_HEIGHT);
        svgShape.setMaxSize(REQUIRED_WIDTH, REQUIRED_HEIGHT);
        svgShape.setStyle("-fx-background-color: black;");
        Scene scene = new Scene(new StackPane(svgShape), 200, 200);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

---

## Use scaleX/Y on SVGPath

You can use the ***scaleX*** / ***scaleY*** to define the width and height of a Shape.

Find the original width/height of the Shape and then find the scaling factor by dividing the required width/height by the original values.

```
Scaling factor for width = required width / original width

Scaling factor for height = required height / original height
```

Now, you can use this scaling factor to scale the shape to the required size.

```
shape.setScaleX(Scaling factor for width);
shape.setScaleY(Scaling factor for height);
```

**MCVE**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.shape.SVGPath;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class SVGPathResize extends Application {

    private static final double REQUIRED_WIDTH = 50.0;
    private static final double REQUIRED_HEIGHT = 30.0;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        SVGPath svg = new SVGPath();
        svg.setContent("M 289.00,74.00 C 299.18,61.21 307.32,52.80 320.00,42.42 331.43,33.07 343.66,26.03 357.00,19.84 427.64,-12.98 509.92,2.91 564.42,58.28 583.93,78.10 595.94,99.15 605.58,125.00 607.76,130.86 611.37,144.75 612.54,151.00 613.15,154.23 613.28,160.06 615.58,162.44 617.49,164.42 624.11,165.84 627.00,166.86 634.80,169.62 639.97,172.04 647.00,176.42 673.69,193.07 692.76,221.39 695.83,253.00 700.60,302.03 676.64,345.41 630.00,364.00 621.17,367.52 608.48,370.99 599.00,371.00 599.00,371.00 106.00,371.00 106.00,371.00 96.50,370.99 87.00,368.97 78.00,366.00 36.29,352.22 6.21,312.25 6.00,268.00 5.77,219.90 34.76,179.34 81.00,165.02 96.78,160.14 107.02,161.00 123.00,161.00 124.59,150.68 130.49,137.79 136.05,129.00 150.70,105.88 173.22,88.99 200.00,82.65 213.13,79.55 219.79,79.85 233.00,80.00 247.37,80.17 264.61,85.94 277.00,93.00 279.11,86.37 284.67,79.45 289.00,74.00 Z");
        resize(svg, REQUIRED_WIDTH, REQUIRED_HEIGHT);
        Scene scene = new Scene(new StackPane(svg), 200, 200);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void resize(SVGPath svg, double width, double height) {

        double originalWidth = svg.prefWidth(-1);
        double originalHeight = svg.prefHeight(originalWidth);

        double scaleX = width / originalWidth;
        double scaleY = height / originalHeight;

        svg.setScaleX(scaleX);
        svg.setScaleY(scaleY);
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

### Additional Explanation

> A vector graphic actually doesn´t have a size

*Well not really*, the path that you define while creating a Shape actually defines the size of the vector graph.

For example, I can create the same shape using :

```
 M 100 100 L 300 100 L 200 300 z
```

and

```
M 10 10 L 30 10 L 20 30 z
```

but the latter is 10 times smaller than the former and so its actual size is also 10 times smaller.

If we scale the smaller triangle by a factor of 10, it will grow and be of the same size.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn´t have time to implement it in my application yet, but it looks promising. But this solution doesn´t "feel right". A vector graphic actually doesn´t have a size. So it actually  doesn´t makes sence, to calculate a scale factor to scale it down. I think the Java API is not well designed at this point.

Comment: I have added information to explain size of vector graph.

Comment: In your region example you used `-fx-background-color` to set fill color but what if I want to change the line color? Normally I'd use `-fx-stroke` for that but it doesn't seem to work with region.